# Spring boot - Joda DateTime serialisation

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jodatime

In an Spring boot app, I have a DTO class with a `org.joda.time.DateTime` field type.

This DTO is the web response body in an endpoint and Spring boot is serialisating it to a **timestamp**.

I don't want that behaviors. Instead of that, I want `DateTime` to be serialised as a POJO.

This is an example:

Actual response:

```
{
  "thisDate": 1566518936800
}
```

Expected response:

```
{
    "thisDate": {
        "monthOfYear": 8,
        "centuryOfEra": 20,
        "yearOfEra": 2019,
        "yearOfCentury": 19,
        "weekyear": 2019,
        "weekOfWeekyear": 34,
        "hourOfDay": 17,
        "minuteOfHour": 8,
        "secondOfMinute": 56,
        "millisOfSecond": 800,
        "secondOfDay": 61736,
        "millisOfDay": 61736800,
        "minuteOfDay": 1028,
        "era": 1,
        "dayOfMonth": 22,
        "dayOfWeek": 4,
        "dayOfYear": 234,
        "year": 2019,
        "chronology": {
            "zone": {
                "fixed": false,
                "uncachedZone": {
                    "cachable": true,
                    "fixed": false,
                    "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
            }
        },
        "millis": 1566518936800,
        "zone": {
            "fixed": false,
            "uncachedZone": {
                "cachable": true,
                "fixed": false,
                "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            "id": "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        "afterNow": false,
        "beforeNow": true,
        "equalNow": false
    }
}
```

I know this is not the most common case but is what I need; actually the most common case is exactly the opposite.

Thanks in advance